# EF Core 5: FreeText Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Byte[] on a Full-Text indexed Byte[] column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-5, freetext

I have the following entity with a property `Content` of type `byte[]`:

```cs
public class Post
{
  [Column(TypeName = "varbinary(max)")]
  [Required]
  public byte[] Content { get; set; }
  
  public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

and the content type in model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .Property(p => p.ContentType)
    .HasComputedColumnSql("'.html'");
```

The Migration:

```cs
migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft_catalog AS DEFAULT", true);
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Posts([Content] TYPE COLUMN ContentType) KEY INDEX PK_Posts", true);
```

`EF.Functions.FreeText` takes a string `propertyReference` and a string `freeText`.

Here, I passed the Column "Content" as a string I got `The expression passed to the 'propertyReference' parameter of the 'FreeText' method is not a valid reference to a property. The expression should represent a reference to a full-text indexed property on the object referenced in the from clause`.

```cs
IQueryable<DataSets.Post> query = db.Posts;

query = query.Where(k => EF.Functions.FreeText("Content", model.keyword));
```

Then, I looked around and found `EF.Property` and used it on `propertyReference` param, Then I got `Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Byte[]`.

```cs
query = query.Where(k => EF.Functions.FreeText(EF.Property<string>(k, "Content"), model.keyword));
```

The following SQL query works perfectly against the database:

```sql
select ID,Title,Description from Posts where FREETEXT(Content,'wolf')
```

Comment: opened an issue: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23921

Comment: I am using EF Core 3.1.5. Can you please share code of your workaround for this issue?

Comment: @Maxcom  replied with a workaround on github https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23921#issuecomment-766350583